# Cannot find namespace NodeJS after webpack upgrade

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I have Angular2 application that is built with WebPack. I upgraded WebPack from v1.8 to v2, and everything seems to be working fine. The only problem is that the old code has the following:

```
import Timer = NodeJS.Timer;
....
apptInterval: Timer;
....
this.apptInterval = setInterval(() => { ... }, 1000);
```

After the upgrade this gives me an error: `TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'NodeJS'.`

tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
   "target": "es5",
   "module": "commonjs",
   "moduleResolution": "node",
   "sourceMap": true,
   "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
   "experimentalDecorators": true,
   "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
   "noImplicitAny": true,
   "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
   }
}
```

The docs for Angular/Webpack no longer have `typings.json`; however, even if I copy from Webpack 1 directory, it doesn't help. The content is typings.json is

```
{
"globalDependencies": {
  "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
  "node": "registry:dt/node"
  }
}
```

Interesting that if I remove references to NodeJS, everything works fine. Like this:

```
apptInterval: any;
....
this.apptInterval = setInterval(() => { ... }, 1000);
```

If I look under F12 debugger, the type of apptInterval is `ZoneTask`. I am sure there is a way to make it strong-typed, but it escapes me. The only suggestion I found was to run `typings install dt~node --global --save-dev` (which essentially updates typings.json, but doesn't help.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

If you also have **tsconfig.app.json** in your working directory, try to add the attribute **node** to the **types** field. Like:

```
  {
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "module": "es6",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "types": ["node"] --> ADD THIS
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: @LuigiRubino Glad i could help!

Comment: It also worked for me!
Note: it also solved the previous webpack compile error:
Cannot find name 'require'. (error ts2304)

Comment: You can also add `types: ["node"]` to **tsconfig.json**, but make sure you don't have an empty `types: []` definition in **tsconfig.app.json** because that overrides it (learned that the hard way...)

Comment: Could you explain why this is the fix?

Answer (score 17):

For TypeScript@2.0+, use `@types`:

```
npm install -D @types/node @types/jasmine
```

If you still want to hang on to `typings`, include `typings/index.d.ts` to your tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "include": [
    "typings"
  ],
  // or
　"files": [
    "typings/index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, neither option made any difference.

Comment: Open your code in VSCode, and see if `NodeJS` exists in the intelliSense. It should be there is you have things setup correclty.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to include `"**/*.d.ts"`  in my tsconfig.app.json within the `include` array. Now my custom type definitions work again.

Comment: This did the trick for me!

Answer (score 4):

Adding node to the types didn't work for me,  `"types": ["node"]` but adding to the type roots did

```
{
  "compilerOptions":
  {
    ...
    "typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm running Angular 12 and I have strict mode enabled, I had to add both [Fzum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7449607/fzum) and [johnny S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1938988/johnny-5)'s answers to my tsconfig.app.json. The only time it didn't throw an error in console is when I had both.

My tsconfig.app.json looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions":
  {
    ...
    "types": ["node"],
    "typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```

Sorry for making this a separate answer, I don't have enough reputation to comment yet