# Cannot find namespace 'NodeJS'. Karma unit Tests

Tags: node.js, angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, karma-webpack

I have created a fresh angular 17 (Node v18.14.1) project.
and tried to run `npm run test`
It fails with the following error.

```
Error: src/app/app.component.ts:13:9 - error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'NodeJS'.
```

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss',
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'angular-tour-of-heroes';
  nodeJsTimeout: NodeJS.Timeout | null = null;
}
```

I already tried to add `types: ["node"]` in `tsconfig.app.json` and also in `tsconfig.json`. Didnt resolve my problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot find namespace NodeJS after webpack upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42940954/cannot-find-namespace-nodejs-after-webpack-upgrade)

Comment: @NarenMurali Already tried that. didnt work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the right solution of not. But the following type worked for me!

`nodeJsTimeout: ReturnType<typeof setInterval> | null = null;`